Build pulling in wrong framework version from ProjectReference
I have a solution which contains several projects.  One of these (call it ProjectA) is set to build for <TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>.  There are a couple of other projects which are only .NET 4.8 and reference ProjectA and they build fine, but the unit test project gets an odd compile error when built via MSBuild on our Jenkins build agent (VS2022 builds just fine)

Assembly 'ProjectA' with identity 'ProjectA, Version=24.3.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter' with identity 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'


Assembly 'ProjectA' with identity 'ProjectA, Version=24.3.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

It seems like it's pulling in the .NET 6 version instead of the .NET 4.8 version.  To confirm that, if I change ProjectA to only build as .net 4.8, the unit test project builds just fine.
After some Googling, I tried including it this way:
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj" >
        <SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=net48</SetTargetFramework>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>

But that didn't help.
I've also tried building the unit test project as both 4.8 and 6 (that's the goal anyway) and it gets the same error.
One thing that may be a clue is that it works fine if I build it using Visual Studio 2022, but the Jenkins build using MSBuild gives the error.  I'm not sure what version of tools are installed on the Jenkins build agents.  I've asked but not gotten
I don't know if it's relevant, but the unit test project pulls in these Nuget packages

Moq 4.18.4
NUnit 4.1.0
NUnit3TestAdapter 4.5.0
Should 1.1.20

There's another error which I assume is related

error CS0119: 'Extensions.Attributes(IEnumerable)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Which is odd because the code in question is doing something like;
var value = node.Attributs["Key"];

Where node is an XmlNode and Attributes is a property of type XmlAttributeCollection.  Again, VS2022 compiles just fine, but MSBuild is confused.
[EDIT:]
I never did figure out why this Unit Test project (.NET 4.8) was getting the .NET 6 assembly from a project reference for a project built as both .NET 4.8 and 6.0.  I have other solutions that do the exact same thing and they work fine.  I eventually gave up and just converted the unit tests to .NET 6 and that solved the problem.

What version of MSBuild do you use on Jenkins? Maybe you have some outdated ones?

@LukaszSzczygielek That's probably the million-dollar question and I suspect you're right. I asked our Jenkins admins and got back a long-winded "answer" that didn't answer the question. I asked follow-up questions and am waiting for a response.

what package version of System.Xml.ReaderWriter are you using and where did it come from?

@MarcGravell I'm not referencing it directly. It seems to just be implied by the version of .net you are using, which is part of why I think it's grabbing the .NET 6 version of ProjectA.

Do you know the command line that the Jenkins pipeline is using to build? Does that command line work on your local system? Separately -- do you get an MSBuild log from the Jenkins pipeline? Is the version of MSBuild in the log?
